# how to switching off stack failure message?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

While running a test suit, when something fails it also show the stack message like this

```
Failures:
1) Should validate labels
    Message: 
      Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".container h1")
    Stack:
      NoSuchElementError: No element found .........................
      .........
     ......
      ....
```

can we switch off this stack output? I have tried

```
protractor conf.js --no-stackTrace
```

also updated conf.js file with settings

```
stackTrace: false,
  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    includeStackTrace: false,
  }
```

but its always showing stack output, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using any reporters in your tests?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using and old protractor (<=1.4 I think), setting both `isVerbose` and `includeStackTrace` to `false` would work for you:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  isVerbose: false,
  includeStackTrace: false
}
```

Unfortunately, nowadays `isVerbose` or `includeStackTrace` would not be recognized in `jasmineNodeOpts` (explanation [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/jasmine-upgrade.md)):

> Similar to jasmine 1.3, you may include `jasmineNodeOpts` in the config
>   file. However, because we changed the runner from
>   "https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode" to
>   "https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm", the options have changed
>   slightly. Notably options `print` and `grep` are new, but we will no
>   longer support options `isVerbose` and `includeStackTrace` (unless, of
>   course, "jasmine-npm" introduces these options).

See also:

- [isVerbose has no effect](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1789)

Comment: not sure why using these options its still throwing messages of stack

Comment: @FarazShuja I've added some more information to the answer. I think you cannot make it "silent" until `jasmine-npm` would support `isVerbose` and `includeStackTrace`..I suggest you create an issue here https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution that I found was located on the protractor github at https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/docs/protractor-configuration.md

You can modify your jasmineNodeOpts like so

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
   ...
   print: function() {}
}
```

And that took care of the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to disable the Stacktraces in my test suite using the following setup in my "conf.js" file:

```
    ...

    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose : false,

        // Use colors in the command line report.
        showColors: true,

        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace : false,

        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,

        // If true, print timestamps for failures
        showTiming: true,

        // Print failures in real time.
        realtimeFailure: true
    }

    ...
```

I found this GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/696) useful with this question. Setting both the "isVerbose" and "includeStackTrace" flags to 'false' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`includeStackTrace` was removed in https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/bf5b076cb8897d844c25baa91c263a12c61e3ab3
so the previous answers did not work for me.

The jasmine-spec-reporter has changed and no longer has a protractor-configuration.md file, so that advice no longer worked for me either.

However, despite the lack of a protractor-configuration.md file, I did find that jasmine-spec-reporter had the working solution for me.
I found that using the jasmine-spec-reporter in this way with Protractor 5.2.0 in my config file:

```
setup = function() {

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TerminalReporter({
         verbosity: 3,
         color: true,
         showStack: false }));
}

exports.config = {
    onPrepare: setup

};
```

The key was to change the `stackTrace` parameter to false in the `TerminalReporter`